# round a number in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a number and I use ROUND() function in SQL :

```
SELECT ROUND(1.81999,2,1)
```

I want the result 1.82, not 1.81.
I don't know where my mistake is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELECT ROUND(1.81999,2,1) Will truncate the result. so the result is 1.81

use this to perform original rounding SELECT ROUND(1.81999,2).

Answer (score 2):

mysql? just ROUND(...,2) work for me.

```
mysql> SELECT ROUND(1.81999,2);
+------------------+
| ROUND(1.81999,2) |
+------------------+
|             1.82 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: @LIX, ok, just don't use 3rd parameter in ROUND function, it could be trancating. so just try `round(1.81999,2)`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. you are specifying 1 in the Function command (3rd parameter of the ROUND() command.
a quote from MSDN about this parameter:
When function is omitted or has a value of 0 (default), numeric_expression is rounded. **When a value other than 0 is specified, numeric_expression is truncated**.

Just change that 1 at the end to a 0 or ommit it entirely and problem solved

Answer (score 0):

See Section "Round to truncate" of [Round(Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx)

This probably depends on the SQL-Dialect you use.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
select round(1.81999,2)
```

Manoj